# Extract text from html files and export as csv

Tags: html, csv, export, extract

I have 5109 html files from my old web-site
i want to extract only text from `<title>Title 1</title>`
and `<span class="mtr_message"> Text exemple 1</span>`
and export results in csv files like this:
Title 1 in first cell and Text exemple 1 in second cell

Comment: Do you need single .csv file, or .csv file for each .html file? What language and environment?

Comment: i need a single .csv file. I can use windows and linux.I have no preference. I'm only interested to make this to work

Comment: Please edit the question and add some HTML file example, at least the relevant part, containing `<title>` and `<span>`. Is the extracted text multiline? And make sure and specify what is the actual HTML files encoding, and extension.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below WSH VBS ode. Paste your paths, save it as .vbs file and run.

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim sSourceFolder, sResultFile, sRes, oFile, sCont

sSourceFolder = "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\tmp" ' source files folder path
sResultFile = "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\tmp\result.csv" ' result csv file path
sRes = ""
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
    For Each oFile In .GetFolder(sSourceFolder).Files
        If LCase(.GetExtensionName(oFile.Name)) = "htm" And oFile.Size > 0 Then
            With .OpenTextFile(oFile.Path, 1, False, -2)
                If .AtEndOfStream Then sCont = "" Else sCont = .ReadAll
                .Close
            End With
            With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
                .Global = True
                .IgnoreCase = True
                .Multiline = True
                .Pattern = "<title>(.*?)</title>[\s\S]*?<span class=""mtr_message"">(.*?)</span>"
                With .Execute(sCont)
                    If .Count = 1 Then sRes = sRes & """" & .Item(0).SubMatches(0) & """, """ & .Item(0).SubMatches(1) & """" & vbCrlf
                End With
            End With
        End If
    Next
    With .OpenTextFile(sResultFile, 2, True, 0)
        .Write sRes
        .Close
    End With
End With
MsgBox "Completed"
```

You might need to change files extension and encoding settings in the code. Currently files with `htm` extension are processed, and are read `.OpenTextFile(oFile.Path, 1, False, -2)` with default encoding `-2` (Unicode - `-1`, ASCII - `0`).

Comment: sorry but is not working, is just making a empty csv file

Comment: @DerenNeagu Check files extension and encoding, I updated the answer.